# Use NetBeans 8 on dual monitor on Windows

Tags: windows, netbeans, multiple-monitors

I'm using NetBeans 8 on Windows 8.1. I've attached an extra monitor to my notebook and I want to use a dual screen set up. I want to have my code on my primary screen and all other panes (projects, databases, tasks, etc.) on another one (i.e. a smaller notebook screen).

The problem is that you can't have the other panes docked on another screen. I end up with many panes on screen, but you can't organize them as easy as with a single screen set up. Here's a little mockup what I want:

[image: Mockup]

I've post a [feature request](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232259), but no one seems to care. But many programmers/designer are using 2 screens. So if you are using a dual screen setup with NetBeans, how are you using it? Are there some extra tools/options that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just found a workaround and possible answer.

I've got my main window (w/ tasks, files, projects) on my secondary screen and dragged my editor (my code) to my (larger) primary screen.

I still can't dock windows outside the main window, but since I want to have only one window outside it, it isn't really necessary.